# Limit CPU time given to an azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app on azure. Once in a while the CPU usage jumps and stays high to the point of none responsiveness.

I would like to be able to profile the process to see what work the CPU is doing 
(no problem doing this normally). however any action to do with the app "container" is super slow because the app is taking up all the CPU time.

Is there a way to limit the app process to, lets say, 80% of the CPU time so that I can get a reading on the cause of the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not. Is it possible for you to scale the instance up and perhaps have some head room with the CPU to work with?

Comment: The CPU still goes to 100%. It's not doing any meaningful work or handling a larger than normal load. Ill try again, maybe I can get the data when one core goes to 100% but the other one is still fine... thanks

Comment: Is this site experiencing traffic when the CPU spikes? Are you running any WebJobs on it?

Comment: No web jobs, and traffic is normal. app runs just fine for hours, then CPU goes up, no exceptions thrown, just slows down from 100 ms per request to 1.5 s . and since the CPU is overloaded I can't profile.